Error when assigning Virtual Network to the Azure Function
I am attempting to assign a VNET to the Azure Function on Flex Consumption plan. I am performing the following steps

Login to Azure Portal and open function resource
Go to Networking
Under Virtual Network Details click on "not configured"
Click "Add virtual network integration"
Select my virtual network resource, and subnet of default (10.0.0.0 - 10.0.0.255)
After about 60s I get a notification "Connecting site to virtual network: Failed to connect to the virtual network: An error has occurred."

I don't have support plan, but when I tried to open ticket I performed the diagnostics and it said that my VNET is good and I should be able to add it.
I expected the VNET to be assigned. The error message does not provide enough information for troubleshooting.

I had similar issues without clear error messages. After filing a support ticket I was pointed to the following documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/flex-consumption-plan#considerations
Make sure your Subnet delegation is set to: Microsoft.App/environments and that the Microsoft.App resource provider is registered for your subscription. Azure Functions Flex Consumption plan is part of Project Legion which brings Azure Container Apps and Azure Functions closer together, hence the requirement of Microsoft.App/environments instead of Microsoft.Website

Same issue, the Microsoft.App resource provider was the issue for me.

I am deploying the Infrastructure via Terraform, and have gotten so used to the Terraform just fixing that for all resources that I did not realize that using the AzAPI provider I have to do this manually.
I added the following to my TF:
// Required for Consumption Flex Plan
resource "azurerm_resource_provider_registration" "microsoft_app" {
  name = "Microsoft.App"
}

and
  # Required for the virtual network integration
  depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_provider_registration.microsoft_app ]

to the azapi resource block

I had a similar experience and got around this by registering my subscription to Microsoft.App and assigning the vnet delegation with Microsoft.App/environments
